# how to fetch large json from a post in angular6/7

Tags: json, angular, large-data

I have migrated a piece of code to be able to export data as excel file in angular.
I assume the fact that the json is well formed and send from the server to the angular side. I can see it in the network frame in th browser.
For small json, it's ok but when the size of the json starts to be large, the answer still failed.
This following code corresponding to the service call

```
 exportSynthesis(recordId: number, moduleId: number) {
    const body = null;

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + `/data`
      + `${recordId}/module/${moduleId}`, body,
      { 
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), 
        observe: 'response', responseType: 'json' }).pipe(
        map((resp: any) => {
          return resp.body;
        }));
  }
```

and here, its the method which manages the return.

```
  exportSynthesis() {
    this.service.exportSynthesis(this.recordId, this.moduleId)
      .subscribe(
        (exportResult) => { this.exportResult = exportResult; },
        err => {
          console.log('err:', err);
          this.errorHandlerService.handleError('failed', err);
          
        },
        () => {
          console.log('json:', this.exportResult);
          const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.exportResult);
          const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
          const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

          const blob = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8' });
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = '(GEO) ' + this.record.label + ' - name.xlsx';
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          a.remove();
        });
  }
```

Currently, i do not manage to understand why it still finish in error and I get only "ok" in the console log.
Any idea?

regards

Comment: Does your JSON object contain a "body" property? As in `{ body: [ /* your data */] }`? I ask because of the `pipe( map((resp: any) => { return resp.body; }))` in your service. Also, it might help to show your console outputs in both cases (small json and long json)

Comment: Your service should look like this  `return this.http.post([...]).pipe((res) => res.body);`. Within the [...] you need to remove the pipe from the `observe`

Comment: @Askirkela, nop. my json is like { [ /*data*/ ] } directly.

Comment: ok @Marek W, i'll test it

Comment: Sorry @MarekW but i have re check and the pipe is already on the post return. could you explain me more your idea cause I'm not sure to have well understand

Comment: Ok I have progress by using this:` 
  exportExcelSynthesis(recordId: number, moduleId: number) {
...
    returnthis.http.post(this.apiUrl + `/geo/v1/synthesis/xls/record/`
      + `${recordId}/module/${moduleId}`, body,
      { 
        headers: headers, 
        observe: 'response' as 'body',
         responseType:  'blob' as 'json' }).
          map((resp: any) => {
            return resp;
          });
  }
`
but now it's a blob and not a json. Do not know how to get my json content

Answer (score 0):

Angular's HttpClientModule default response is a json.
Your problem is that you try to access the `body` property of the HTTP response, but Angular interprets that as you trying to access the `body` property in the body of the response.

Remove `observe` and `responseType` from your post request and treat the response as a json. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

find:
just need to use text as json

```
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + `/geo/v1/synthesis/xls/record/`
      + `${recordId}/module/${moduleId}`, body,
      { 
        headers: headers, 
        observe: 'response',
         responseType:  'text' as 'json'}).
          map((resp: any) => {
            return resp.body;      
          });
  }
```